# Casting a function when using void pointers (CUBA Nint routine)

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, casting

I am not a good programmer to be honest. I am tasked with changing out a numerical integration routine with the CUBA library. But this is not necessarily important. What I am given is a custom-made routine where I have many functions that get integrated, defined like:

```
    float spectra(float x[],float)
```

that get passed to a numerical vegas routine

```
    float integrate ( float (*fxn)(float[],float), unsigned long ncall, int itmx )
```

by calling

```
    integrate(spectra,ncall,itmx);
```

that then gets passed on to the actual routine. This is all fine.

Now, in the CUBA routines I do the integration with:

```
Cuhre(NDIM, NCOMP, Integrand, USERDATA, NVEC, ... ,integral, ...);
```

Where what matters is Integrand is the function, and USERDATA is a void pointer to pass any extra things you need to Integrand. Sort of like the GSL routines.

I DON'T want to rewrite all the "spectra" functions to have the proper form for the CUBA routines. I just want to have a wrapper in between.

Integrand has the casting :

```
    static int Integrand(const int *ndim, const cubareal xx[], const int *ncomp, cubareal ff[], void *userdata);
```

Wher xx[] are inputs, (only 1 for now), ff[] are the outputs (also 1). userdata is the void pointer that I need to typecast.

My goal is to make a wrapper such that anywhere in the program where it calls:
integrate(function,...)
I can replace as I wish with 
integrateCUBA(function,...)

My attempt is to define the Integrand function as a blank template, that gets passed USERDATA, which is type-cast into this float function, and then from there it should be done. What do I put in the statement below?

```
static int Integrand(const int *ndim, const cubareal xx[], const int *ncomp, cubareal ff[], void *userdata) {
    #define f ff[0]
    float xxx[ndim];  //xx is inputs, ff is outputs
    xxx[0] = xx[0];   //ndim is 1 for now.

    //here I try to cast this void pointer
    float (*fxn)(float[],float) = NULL;


     // What do I put here??????
    *fxn = ???


    f = fxn(xxx,0.0);

    return f ;
}
```

Then in the end I'll have a routine :

```
float integrateCUBA ( float (*fxn)(float[],float), unsigned long ncall, int itmx )
{
    int comp, nregions, neval, fail;
    cubareal integral[NCOMP], error[NCOMP], prob[NCOMP];

    Cuhre(NDIM, NCOMP, Integrand, &fxn, NVEC, ...
```

where I send it "&fxn" through the USERDATA pointer.

I hope I'm being clear. Really what I'm trying to do is pass a pointer to a function "float (*fxn)(float[],float)" through a void pointer, and then type-cast it back properly.

This code is written in C/C++ (a horrible bastardization from a bunch of old scientific codes by people other than me.) It will be compiled in c++11, so if theres an easy static cast method I can use that too.

Thank you very much for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just cast, but the syntax is on the unreadable side:

```
float (*fxn)(float[],float) = (float (*)(float[],float)) userdata;
                       // or static_cast<float (*)(float[],float)>(userdata);
f = fxn(xxx,0.0);
```

Using a typedef can improve readability:

```
typedef float (*Function)(float[],float);

Function fxn = (Function) userdata;
```